# System hangs on reboot and poweroff

Tags: shutdown, freeze, reboot

My laptop started hanging several days ago, this is the last message it prints. I am running Ubuntu 21.10. What can be done to make this work again without having to disable updates?

[image: This is the last message it prints]

---

**EDIT:**

The problem started after the kernel 5.13.0-22-generic was upgraded to 5.13.0-23-generic. When I boot using the former kernel image in grub, the correct behavior is restored (i.e. the system shuts down cleanly). Note that for this I changed the grub config by adding the following two lines to make grub boot the same image as previously:

```
vi /etc/default/grub
   GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
   GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
update-grub
```

This of course does not solve the problem, only avoids it.

See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1956821

Comment: could be this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/finalrd/+bug/1905166

Comment: I don't think that bug is relevant / critical. The message says "ignoring".

Comment: @Community I will reword, although isn't it obvious? I would like to be able to shut down and restart the laptop with the latest ububtu update....

Comment: Someone in a redhat folder wrote about disabling some BIOS options to get this managed... https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1825298 -- 'Go into the BIOS of the laptop, under Virtualization, and DISABLE the option "VT for Direct I/O".'